# Blackberry 10 developers device "Error:device"

Tags: blackberry-simulator, blackberry-10

I am getting error "Error:device" on blackberry 10 developers device. I get this error when I am installing the unsigned .bar file to the device.

It was working fine earlier but suddenly it started showing this error.
I tried to reboot the device, but still getting same error.

Answer (score 0):

Which development environment/SDK are you using to get this error? Native/WebWorks/Air/Android.

Please tag your question according to the SDK to ensure you get a prompt response. Example (blackberry-webworks)

Answer (score 0):

had to disable Automatic in USB mode to deploy from a linux host ...